# Mongo DB, how to do restriction on a calculated field?

Tags: mongodb, projection

Just starting with mongo and I'm trying to do something that look simple.

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').find({ 
    "myProperty" : {
        $gt: 10 - anotherPropertyOfMyObject
    }
})
```

Tried with $elemMatch and projection but no dice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/), [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) and [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) to match, to find greater then and for the difference of the same document fields respectively

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').find({
  "$expr": { "$gt": [{ "$subtract": [ 10, "$anotherPropertyOfMyObject" ] }, "$myProperty" ] }
})
```